# Can I play Final Fantasy 3 (mobile) with any jobs?

Tags: final-fantasy-3

I'm playing [*Final Fantasy III* (remake, mobile)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.square_enix.android_googleplay.FFIII_GP&hl=en) and I choose not to use any black magic casters. I was planning on not using those for the whole game but I was forced too: when your whole team are mini, physical performs very poorly. It seems like you can't go through that part without a black or red mage. Now I'm wondering:

- Am I going to be forced to use black magic again ? Should I keep at least 1 black mage in my team ?
- Are there any other jobs that you absolutely need to train to complete the game?

I'd rather know early so I can train in those jobs.

Comment: why are the mages not getting any love?

Comment: @Quinma Probably because [they smell](http://www.nuklearpower.com/2001/08/25/episode-071-sometimes-he-should-really-keep-quiet/).

Comment: If I recall there is a boss that is VERY difficult (possibly impossible) without a Dragoon. But other than that the game can be beaten using any combination of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any combination will work. It's been a while since I went through the 'small' part, but even then you should just buy some basic dmg spells, and temp switch other classes to lowbie casters. In fact, for 99% of the game, black magic is weak, and vastly overshadowed by any melee: while the 9,999 dmg cap is visually reported, my knight and monk have hit for 59,999 (at lvl 98/job level 99) (per achievement page, so this is probably the hard internal cap). There is also certainly no need for a dragoon. If a boss is hard, keep levelling up, then come back.

Simply choosing your favorite classes is fine (a white mage, for heals, though, is recommended).